# Python: Adding hour vector to date vector elementwise

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have an array of dates as:

```
>>> dates
array([datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0))], dtype=object)
```

I have corresponding array of hours of same size as dates:

```
numpy.asarray([3,5,2])
```

I want to generate the following:

```
>>> datesPlusHour
array([datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 3, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 5, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 2, 0))], dtype=object)
```

i.e. add hour vector to date vector element wise. I am hoping to use something better than a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is creating `timedelta`s from your hours as a numpy array tehm add it with your dates:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dates = np.array([datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0),
...        datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0),
...        datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
>>>
>>> h = np.asarray([3,5,2])
>>> hours = np.array([datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in h])
>>>
>>> dates + hours
array([datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 3, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 5, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 2, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Or as a more Numpythonic approach you can use `np.vectorize` in order to apply a function to your array's items instead of using a list comprehension.

```
>>> f = np.vectorize(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(hours=x))
>>> f(h) + dates
array([datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 3, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 5, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 2, 0)], dtype=object)
```